# set subset of another set SML

Tags: set, subset, sml

I am trying to implement set subset of another set. However I cannot get it working with the following example {{{},1}} and {{1,{}}} I have tried everything I am capable of. My main aim to do set equality which returns a true in this case. For start I would like to get my subset working then implement the set equality.

```
 datatype expression = SET of expression list | TUPLE of expression list | INT of int    
fun member(a,SET y) = List.exists (fn x => x=a) y;

fun member1 (n,nil) = false
|   member1 (n, SET h::r) = (n=h) orelse member1 (n,r);

fun isIn value list = List.exists (fn x=>value=x) list;

 fun isSubset' ([],s') = true 
   | isSubset' (e::s,s') = isIn e s' andalso isSubset' (s,s');

 fun isSubset(SET s,SET s') = isSubset'(s,s');


 fun subsetEQ [] S' = true 
    | subsetEQ (x::xs) S' = isIn x S' andalso subsetEQ xs S';
      fun setEq (SET S,SET S') = (subsetEQ S S') andalso (subsetEQ S' S) ;



val x0 = INT 8;
val x1 = SET [SET[SET[],INT 1]];
val x2 = SET [SET[INT 1,SET[]]];
val x3 = setEq (x1,x2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you have is that in e.g.

```
fun isIn value list = List.exists (fn x=>value=x) list;
```

You are using regular equality, but for nested sets you need the notion of set equality which you are trying to define.

What you really need is three mutually recursive functions, one for membership, one for subset, and one for equality. Furthermore, rather than having a host of annoying messages `Warning: match nonexhaustive`, why not supply reasonable definitions for all patterns? The following modification of your code is the sort of thing you could do (note the keyword `and` rather than `fun` for the second and third of the three mutually-recursive functions):

```
datatype nested = SET of nested list | INT of int 

fun member (_, INT i) = false
|   member (SET x, SET y) = List.exists (fn z => equals(SET x, z)) y
|   member (INT i, SET y) = List.exists (fn x => x = INT i) y

and equals (INT i, INT j) = i = j
|   equals (INT i, SET y) = false
|   equals (SET x, INT j) = false
|   equals (SET x, SET y) = subset (SET x, SET y) andalso subset(SET y, SET x)

and subset (_, INT i) = false
|   subset (INT i, _) = false
|   subset (SET [], SET y) = true
|   subset (SET (x::xs), SET y) = member (x, SET y) andalso subset(SET xs, SET y);

val x0 = INT 8;
val x1 = SET [SET[SET[],INT 1]];
val x2 = SET [SET[INT 1,SET[]]];
val x3 = equals (x1,x2);
```

The above compiles with no warnings and with `x3 = true`.